# Implement Cookie based stickiness in a Rotating proxy server

Tags: python, web-scraping, haproxy

I am using HAProxy(open to alternatives) as a Rotating proxy server for my python crawler. I want a persistence session in HAProxy.
But not able to do so, because HAProxy cant change the headers of an HTTPS request.
Am using this

```
backend bk_web
balance round-robin
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
```

my HAProxy server is not adding this cookie to the HTTPS request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Session persistence is usually when you want to persist your client to a specific backend server. However, you seem to indicate that you want to use it as a rotating proxy server, so I'm not quite sure you really want session persistence.
Are you terminating HTTPS in HAProxy? You need to terminate HTTPS in HAProxy (or any proxy for that matter) in order to modify headers within an HTTPS session. Alternatively, you can use HAProxy's stick-tables for persisting TCP connections where header modification is not possible or `balance source`